# how to get child instance of a foreignkeyfield in a query

Tags: django, foreign-keys

i have three classes. Place is foreignkey of Activity(where the activity takeplace), Park and Restarant are inherited from Place.

```
 class Activity(Model):
    place=ForeignKeyField('Place')
    ....

class Place(Model):
    address=CharField(max_length=200)
    ....
class Park(Place):
    ticket_price=Decimal()
    ....
class Restarant(Place):
    manager_name=CharField(max_length=100)
```

how can i get the real type of 'Place' in a query on Activity,so i can get the additional attributes of child type.

```
activity_list= Activity.objects.all()
```

all the activity_list[n].place are 'Place' ,neither Park or Restarant, so i can't get 'ticket_price' or 'manager_name' directly.

i have checked the model-utils, and can't find a easy way to do this.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
activity_list= Activity.objects.all()
for act in activity_list:
    for b in act.place.__class__.__bases__:
       print b.__name__
```

Comment: the result is the name of the  type, not an instance of the real type,right?

Comment: @phiree yes, there isnot actually instance in this case, because ``place`` is the indirect instance of base class

Answer (score 0):

> inspect.getmro(cls)
>
> Return a tuple of class cls’s base classes, including cls, in method resolution order. No class appears more than once in this tuple. Note that the method resolution order depends on cls’s type. Unless a very peculiar user-defined metatype is in use, cls will be the first element of the tuple.

try:

```
import inspect
for activity in activity_list:
    print inspect.getmro(activity.place)
```

or try :

```
for activity in activity_list:
    print activity.place._type()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Django [Inheritance Managers](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html) for this, from [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils). It allows you to do exactly what you want...you said you checked model-utils to do this, but it didn't work. It should work -- what did you try with django-model-utils? You need to add this line to the parent model of `Place`:

```
objects = InheritanceManager()
```

I haven't tried this with your exact model design, but have you tried something like:

```
places = Activity.objects.all().values_list('place_id', flat=True)
places_of_right_type = Place.objects.filter(pk__in=places).select_subclasses()
```

?

------ UPDATE --------
Not sure this will work, but throwing it out there as an idea...would only work for a get(), not all():

```
places = Activity.objects.get(pk=#).place.objects.select_subclasses()
```

The docs say that you can call select_subclasses() on the InheritanceManager itself, which is stored in `.objects`.

Comment: yes, i am using model-util in the project, and your solution surely can work. but what i am wandering is : can i get the real instance just querying on Activity?  no need another query on Place.   i think there is no way to do this in a single query.  thanks for your attention any way.